# How do I add a custom validator in my FormRequest?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a rule (`foobar`) that is not built in to Laravel that I want to use within my extended `FormRequest`. How can I create a custom validator for that specific rule?

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'id' => ['required', 'foobar']
    ];
}
```

I know `Validator::extend` exists but I don't want to use facades. I want it "built in" to my `FormRequest`. How do I do that and is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to have your custom validation method by creating a `validator` property to your class and setting it to `app('validator')`. You can then with that property run `extend`, just like with the facade.

Create a `__construct` method and add this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->validator = app('validator');

    $this->validateFoobar($this->validator);
}
```

Then create a new method called `validateFoobar` that take the `validator` property as the first argument and run `extend` on that, just like with the facade.

```
public function validateFoobar($validator) {
    $validator->extend('foobar', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return ! MyModel::where('foobar', $value)->exists();
    });
}
```

More detail about `extend` is available [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

In the end, your `FormRequest` could look like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\MyModel;
use App\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->validator = app('validator');

        $this->validateFoobar($this->validator);
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'id' => ['required', 'foobar']
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            'id.required' => 'You have to have an ID.',
            'id.foobar' => 'You have to set the foobar value.'
        ];
    }

    public function authorize() { return true; }

    public function validateFoobar($validator) {
        $validator->extend('foobar', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
            return ! MyModel::where('category_id', $value)->exists();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this and also make a custom error message for the new validation filter?

Comment: @JimRubenstein: You can put custom messages in `/resources/lang/de/validation.php` like this:
`<?php

return [

    'custom' => [
        'id' => [
            'foobar' => 'Custom Message',
        ],
    ],

];`

Comment: @JimRubenstein, you can use the [messages](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L213) method in your FormRequest. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: @Marwelln after some research, there's also an undocumented 3rd parameter to `Validator::extend` that accepts the error message. I like the `FormRequest::messages` approach better, though!

@roNn23 I knew about the language files - that's more abstraction than I need at the moment though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From version 5.4 you can use the [`withValidator`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#creating-form-requests) method to extend the rule.

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'id' => ['required', 'foobar']
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            'id.required' => 'You have to have an ID.',
            'id.foobar' => 'You have to set the foobar value.'
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->addExtension('foobar', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return ! MyModel::where('category_id', $value)->exists();
        });
    }
}
```