# Custom validation rules in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

How can I add correctly custom validation rule in Laravel 5?

In Laravel 4 it was placed in some autoloaded file:

```
Validator::register('alpha_spaces', function($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match('/^([-a-z0-9_-\s])+$/i', $value);
});
```

Comment: I thought it was "extend" rather than "register"? Maybe I'm remembering incorrectly.

Comment: See my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26616023/397195) if you are using `FormRequest`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
     Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
         return $value == 'foo'; 
});
```

I think you only need to change 'register' with 'extend'.